# How to update a varray type within a table with a simple update statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table that has a column defined as varray of a defined type. The production table is way more complicated then the following example.

I am able to select the single columns within the type of the varray. But I would like to update the table with a simple update statement (rather than going through a pl/sql routine).

If this is not possible (and I must go through a pl/sql routine) what is a smart and easy way to code this?

```
update (select l.id, t.* from my_object_table l, table(l.object_list) t) 
set value2 = 'obj 4 upd' 
where value1 = 10 

ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here
```

Here the full example of types etc.

```
create or replace type my_object 
as object(
      value1                    number,
      value2                    varchar2(10),
      value3                    number);

create or replace type my_object_varray as varray(100000000) of my_object;

create table my_object_table (id number not null, object_list my_object_varray);

insert into my_object_table 
   values (1, my_object_varray (
                    my_object(1,'object 1',10), 
                    my_object(2,'object 2',20),
                    my_object(3,'object 3',30) 
                 )
          );

insert into my_object_table 
   values (2, my_object_varray (
                    my_object(10,'object 4',10), 
                    my_object(20,'object 5',20),
                    my_object(30,'object 6',30) 
                 )
          );

select l.id, t.* from my_object_table l, table(l.object_list) t;

Type created.
Type created.
Table created.
1 row created.
1 row created.

        ID     VALUE1 VALUE2         VALUE3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 object 1           10
         1          2 object 2           20
         1          3 object 3           30
         2         10 object 4           10
         2         20 object 5           20
         2         30 object 6           30

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [update multiple records in multiple nested tables in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256433/update-multiple-records-in-multiple-nested-tables-in-oracle)

Comment: The possible duplicate question is not the same and the solution does not work for me. I do not have a nested table but I have a varray type making an array of an object type. But thanks for the suggestion. I tried the solution but they are not applicable to my problem. Please leave this question open as it is distinct.

Comment: Yes, I see. My mistake, sorry. The close vote retracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can update a single object's value within a `varray` from plain SQL, as there is no way to reference the `varray` index. (The link Alessandro Rossi posted seems to support this, though not necessarily for that reason). I'd be interested to be proven wrong though, of course.

I know you aren't keen on a PL/SQL approach but if you do have to then you could do this to just update that value:

```
declare
  l_object_list my_object_varray;
  cursor c is
    select l.id, l.object_list, t.*
    from my_object_table l,
    table(l.object_list) t
    where t.value1 = 10
    for update of l.object_list;
begin
  for r in c loop
    l_object_list := r.object_list;
    for i in 1..l_object_list.count loop
      if l_object_list(i).value1 = 10 then
        l_object_list(i).value2 := 'obj 4 upd';
      end if;
    end loop;

    update my_object_table
    set object_list = l_object_list
    where current of c;
  end loop;
end;
/

anonymous block completed

select l.id, t.* from my_object_table l, table(l.object_list) t;

        ID     VALUE1 VALUE2         VALUE3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 object 1           10 
         1          2 object 2           20 
         1          3 object 3           30 
         2         10 obj 4 upd          10 
         2         20 object 5           20 
         2         30 object 6           30
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/51f29/1).

If you're updating other things as well then you might prefer a function that returns the object list with the relevant value updated:

```
create or replace function get_updated_varray(p_object_list my_object_varray,
  p_value1 number, p_new_value2 varchar2)
return my_object_varray as
  l_object_list my_object_varray;
begin
  l_object_list := p_object_list;
  for i in 1..l_object_list.count loop
    if l_object_list(i).value1 = p_value1 then
      l_object_list(i).value2 := p_new_value2;
    end if;
  end loop;

  return l_object_list;
end;
/
```

Then call that as part of an update; but you still can't update your in-line view directly:

```
update (
  select l.id, l.object_list
  from my_object_table l, table(l.object_list) t
  where t.value1 = 10
)
set object_list = get_updated_varray(object_list, 10, 'obj 4 upd');

SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
```

You need to update based on relevant the ID(s):

```
update my_object_table
set object_list = get_updated_varray(object_list, 10, 'obj 4 upd')
where id in (
  select l.id
  from my_object_table l, table(l.object_list) t
  where t.value1 = 10
);

1 rows updated.

select l.id, t.* from my_object_table l, table(l.object_list) t;

        ID     VALUE1 VALUE2         VALUE3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 object 1           10 
         1          2 object 2           20 
         1          3 object 3           30 
         2         10 obj 4 upd          10 
         2         20 object 5           20 
         2         30 object 6           30
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c1c23/1).

If you wanted to hide the complexity even further you could create a view with an instead-of trigger that calls the function:

```
create view my_object_view as
  select l.id, t.* from my_object_table l, table(l.object_list) t
/

create or replace trigger my_object_view_trigger
instead of update on my_object_view
begin
  update my_object_table
  set object_list = get_updated_varray(object_list, :old.value1, :new.value2)
  where id = :old.id;
end;
/
```

Then the update is pretty much what you wanted, superficially at least:

```
update my_object_view
set value2 = 'obj 4 upd'
where value1 = 10;

1 rows updated.

select * from my_object_view;

        ID     VALUE1 VALUE2         VALUE3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 object 1           10 
         1          2 object 2           20 
         1          3 object 3           30 
         2         10 obj 4 upd          10 
         2         20 object 5           20 
         2         30 object 6           30
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55f80/1).

Comment: Very nice. Overriding the view update with a trigger method makes the final update statement very readable.

Answer (score 2):

As the Oracle documentation states [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjcol.htm#ADOBJ7278)

> While nested tables can also be changed in a piecewise fashions,
>   varrays cannot.

There is no way to modify VARRAYS in piecewise fashion. The only things you could do are:

- Convert the data type of your fied into a NESTED TABLE (CREATE TYPE xxx AS TABLE OF yyy)
- Fetch the varray of the row you want to change, modify with in your client language, then update the row to set the modified value on it.

Comment: Thanks for quoting the Oracle documentation that makes it clear that I cannot get around a PL/SQL routine. So my second question was what is a smart and easy way to do that. Converting the data type is not an option in the scenario I have (if it would be an option I would get rid of the nested column altogether)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT value2
    FROM
        TABLE(SELECT object_list FROM my_object_table)
    WHERE value1 = 10
) t
SET t.value2 = 'object 4 upd';
```

I couldn't test this query, use with care. I'm not sure Oracle can actually do that...

Comment: [Apparently not (SQLFiddle blows off with a java.lang.NullPointerException)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad371/4)

Comment: Although you're probably right, sometimes sqlfiddle is not working well, especially the java part (already had an issue before)

Comment: The requirements are a bit off-kilter anyways - VALUE2 is a VARCHAR2(10) but the new string ('object 4 upd') is 12 characters. :-)

Comment: Same error message. Sorry for the update with a too long string, will update the original question.